# Oracle Backup and restore constraints to allow changing a column type

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key, constraints

I need to change a column type in more than 200 tables I am following the next recipe:

1. Disable all foreign constraints if the column is referenced by any FK
2. Store columns in varray and Drop primary key if the column is part of a PK
3. Create a temporal new column in the table with the same type
4. Update the temporal new column with original values
5. Delete values from original column
6. Change column type of original column
7. Update original column with temporal column values
8. Restore primary key if applied
9. Enable FK if applied

I am having some issues with the following cases

. When a primary key is compound (Multiple columns)
. I need to store the original FK and PK signature to allow me to restore them after the change

------- My ideas --------

1. Backup all_constraints and all_cons_columns records in a temporary table and after changing the column type resstoring the constraints info.
2. Keep with the same idea of storing the FK and PK signature to restore them after changing the column type

¿ Any suggestions ? would be appreaciate it, thx!!

Comment: What are the 'old' and 'new' datatypes of the column being changed?

Comment: old type is NUMBER(10) new type is VARCHAR2(10)

Comment: You might want to take a look at the DBMS_REDEFINITION package (which I believe has been a standard part of Oracle since 9i), which may be able to help you with all these issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the old CTAS then rename method:

basically:

1. create new table as select c1,c1,c3 ... from old table (include data
   type transformation here;
2. establish any indexes, constraints ...
3. drop old table (may need to disable donstraints first)
4. rename new table to old table